# Undefined in console on GET request in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm creating a script which is going to automatically receive data from API and store it in MongoDB at specific UTC time.

I use [Node-Schedule](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule) for scheduling a task at specific time. 
[CoinMarketCap](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1CryptocurrencyListingsLatest) API for receiving a real time data.

Problem: I receive an undefined in console every second(since the node-schedule is configured to call the code every second). I was looking for any syntax errors or errors in API and wasn't successful. I understand that I receive undefined cause the function doesn't return anything. 
Currently doesn't have any ideas what wrong with it at all.
All API keys and DB username password was correct I checked it as well.

Goal: To have the script which is automatically receives data from API and stores it MongoDB collection.

**Full Code**

```
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb');
const schedule = require('node-schedule');
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

const saveToDatabase = function(BTCdata) {
    const url = 'mongodb+srv://name:password@cluster0-1kunr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

    MongoClient.connect(url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, (err, db) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        const dbo = db.db('Crypto');
        const myobj = { Name: 'BTC', Volume: 'BTCdata' };
        dbo.collection('Crypto-Values').insertOne(myobj, (error, res) => {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log('1 document inserted');
            db.close();
        });
    });
};

function request(method, url) {
    return new Promise(((resolve, reject) => {
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
        xhr.onload = resolve;
        xhr.onerror = reject;
        xhr.send();
    }));
}

const j = schedule.scheduleJob('* * * * * *', () => {
    request(
            'GET',
            'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE',
        )
        .then((r1) => {
            const x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

            const BTCdata = x1.data.find((d) => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.USD.volume_24h; // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API


            console.log(BTCdata);
            // Saving to database
            saveToDatabase(BTCdata);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
```

**EDIT1:**
This is a console log of x1 value.
[image: x1 Console Log]
**EDIT2:**
Was missing this part -

```
var request = require('request');
```

After it was added I start receiving a new error in my console which is :

```
events.js:287
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Invalid URI "GET"
at Request.init
at new Request
at request
at Job.job
at Job.Invoke
at Users/path to node modules/node-schedule
at Timeout.onTimeout
```

**EDIT3:**
After correction to the code with @Sureshprajapati answer.
New error appears - `TypeError: Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined`
Trying to find solution by myself. Still looking for any advice. Thank you.

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');

requestPromise.get({
  uri: 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE',
  json: true
}).then(r1 => {
  const x1 = JSON.parse(r1.target.responseText);

  const BTCdata = x1.data.find(d => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.USD
    .volume_24h; // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API

  console.log(BTCdata);
  // Saving to database
  saveToDatabase(BTCdata);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: What is x1 value? Can you add a log and check?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Main question edited. This is a array of all cryptocurrencies from CoinMarketCap.  Screenshot attached, you can look.

Comment: Can you see if your record is present in the Array  with exact structure and expected keys?

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Yes, it was working before i start adding scheduling for script. As well with that I forgot to add require request. After I add require request I start receiving a new error - "Invalid URI "GET"". Main question edited with new error.

Comment: Did you mean `var request = require('request-promise'); ?`

Comment: @SureshPrajapati Just added you `var request = require('request-promise');` And I receive error `Cannot find module 'request'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request` supports both streaming and callback interfaces natively. If you'd like request to return a Promise instead, you can use an alternative interface wrapper for request. These wrappers can be useful if you prefer to work with Promises, or if you'd like to use async/await in ES2017.

[request-promise](https://github.com/request/request-promise) (uses Bluebird Promises)

This module is installed via npm:

```
npm install --save request
npm install --save request-promise
```

Coming to modifying your code as per documentation:

```
var requestPromise = require('request-promise');

requestPromise.get({
  uri: 'http://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest?CMC_PRO_API_KEY=API-KEY-HERE',
  json: true
}).then(x1 => {

  const BTCdata = x1.data.find(d => d.symbol === 'BTC').quote.USD
    .volume_24h; // creating a variable to store a BTC request from API

  console.log(BTCdata);
  // Saving to database
  saveToDatabase(BTCdata);
}).catch(err => {
  console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: it works for me. Thank you so much for explaining difference. Upvoted, confirmed for correct answer! Thanks!